# Exscript: Access to remote network devices via a bastion host while still using device specific drivers to recognize the device prompt

Tags: python, exscript

I am trying to access network devices that are accessible only if you ssh from a bastion host that runs SunOS (no proxycommand support or ssh tunneling)

My approach would be to use the generic driver to access the bastion host. and from there to use ' ssh remotedevicename' to connect to the remote device.

In my case the remote device requires only one step authentication which drops me to the # prompt (level 15 access for Cisco devices)

I manage to successfully authenticate but I can not send commands

Here is what I use

```
conn = SSH2()  
conn.debug=5  
conn.set_driver('generic')          
conn.connect('bastion')  
conn.login(account)        
print conn.response
conn.send('ssh 1.1.1.1\n')
conn.expect('Password:')
print conn.response
conn.send('password\n')
```

At this point I think that I should change the driver with

```
conn.set_driver('nxos')
conn.execute ("show cdp neighbors\n")
```

but after doing that the script times out with

```
nxos: Sending 'show cdp neighbors\n\r'
nxos: Expecting a prompt
nxos: Expected pattern: ["'[\\\\r\\\\n][\\\\-\\\\w+\\\\.:/]+(?:\\\\([^\\\\)]+\\\\))?[>#] ?$'"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 1):

The above sequence is fine
I was missing "terminal length 0" and the script was stuck with that